# how to use tsql uniqueidentifier in a where not in clause

Tags: t-sql, comparison, uniqueidentifier

Trying to see if a uniqueidentifier exists in a where not in clause which contains a list of uniqueidentifiers... but this is not working.

```
   select distinct cast(a.person_id as varchar(50))
   from appointments a
   where a.appt_date = '20140206'
       and a.last_name like 'Smith123%'
       and cast(a.person_id as varchar(50)) not in 
                    (select cast(aa.person_id as varchar(50)) 
                    from appointments aa 
                    where aa.appt_date < '20140206')
```

If I run the base query for Smith123%  I get a uniqueidentifier.

Then if I run the not in select with an order by person_id  I get many `person_id` values, but I do not see the uniqueidentifier I found earlier.... so I don't know why I don't get my one uniqueidentifier to display

Thanks in advance for any assistance
Dean-O

Comment: Are you sure the person_id you’ve found in the first query hasn’t got an appointment before 20140206?

Comment: yes.  I ran the not in select and then sorted them in excell and did not find my person_id

Comment: Do you perhaps have a null value in the aa.person_id field?

Comment: Bingo null person_id thanks a million  How do I give points to mmarie